# If textField is empty, do not filter my array to nothing

Tags: objective-c

This works fine if the `textField` is containing any text. But if the `textField` is empty, no objects are added.

How to tell this piece of code that if the `textField` is empty, *all* objects should be added to `resultObjectsArray`?

```
resultObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary *object in allObjectsArray)
{

    NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textField text]];
    NSString *wineName = [wine objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSRange range = [wineName rangeOfString:nameString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if ((range.location != NSNotFound))
        [resultObjectsArray addObject:object];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resultObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *nameString = [textField text];
for(NSDictionary *object in allObjectsArray)
{
    if ([nameString length] > 0)
    {
        NSString *wineName = [wine objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSRange range = [wineName rangeOfString:nameString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if ((range.location != NSNotFound))
            [resultObjectsArray addObject:object];
    }
    else
    {
        [resultObjectsArray addObject:object];
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need:

```
NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textField text]];
```

as

```
NSString *nameString = [textField text];
```

is sufficient.  Also it won't change inside the `for` loop so can be initialised outside of it.

Comment: Correct answer,but I would check for empty textfield before entering the loop and only enter the loop when neccessary. This way you can set the resultObjectArray to the allObjectsArray without the multiple addObject calls and enumerations. Performance-wise the loop surely won't cause much overhead unless it's really a huge array. But the code would look cleaner (to me).

Comment: @Mario I think if I was writing this I would do that same.  The code I provided attempted to stay as similar to the OP's code as possible.  Not all code written in answers is meant to be used verbatim.

Comment: Correct. I use answer to get the idea, then I implement it into my real case which is a bit different.

Comment: Added my finished code for this as another answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

That's how the code ended up looking like using the answer from @trojanfoe. (I've excluded my other search criterias).

```
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{  

BOOL textFieldIsEdited = NO;
if ([[textField text] length] > 0)
{
textFieldIsEdited = YES;
}

resultObjectsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary *wine in allObjectsArray)
{

    BOOL nameMatch = YES;
    if (textFieldIsEdited) {
        NSString *wineName = [wine objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSString *nameString = [textField text];
        NSRange range = [wineName rangeOfString:nameString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
            nameMatch = NO;
        }
    }

    if ((nameMatch != NO))
        [resultObjectsArray addObject:wine];
}
```